# Visual Studio 2012 ide scrollbar collapsed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, slider, scrollbar

Suddenly the scrollbar on the visual studio code viewer collapsed I don't know how and why it did.

I couldn't find anything related to this nowhere

[image]

http://i57.tinypic.com/2csjdco.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Yea, it is stuck like this a few days now...

Comment: That happened to me too, right now. Restarting the computer makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

1. Go to %System Drive%\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
2. Rename the cache file (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache) present there to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache_1'.
3. Restart the visual studio.